# Android logs / logcat logs are unclear

Tags: android, logging

I have a problem with the logs shown in IntelijIdea 11.0.2 (maybe in others versions too, but this is the version I use now; even I do not know if has to do with idea). The logs on some devices (like Nexus 7 or Motorola Xoom) are very unclear.
Ex.:

```
  GC_CONCURRENT freed 391K, 7% free 7847K/8388K, paused 3ms+4ms, total 41ms
    [ 01-10 16:29:31.475  9132: 9132 I/Process  ]
    Sending signal. PID: 9132 SIG: 9
    [ 01-10 16:29:31.485   478:  478 I/WindowState ]
    WIN DEATH: Window{41813ca8 u0 asd.ssssge.namespace.test.asa/asd.ssssge.namespace.test.asa.TestActivity}
    [ 01-10 16:29:31.485   478: 6135 I/ActivityManager ]
    Process asd.ssssge.namespace.test.asa (pid 9132) has died.
    [ 01-10 16:29:31.505   478:  802 W/InputMethodManagerService ]
    Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 9132 uid 10073
    [ 01-10 16:29:31.885  7863: 7867 D/dalvikvm ]
    GC_CONCURRENT freed 389K, 7% free 7844K/8384K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 18ms
    [ 01-10 16:29:32.595  7863: 7863 D/MessageManager ]
    Queueing message Intent { (has extras) } on channel 0
    [ 01-10 16:29:32.595  7863: 7885 D/MessageManager ]
    Attempting to dispatch message { what=0 when=-1ms obj=com.example.testapp$Message@414d70b8 }
    [ 01-10 16:29:32.595   478:  847 W/InputMethodManagerService ]
    Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@417f1c18 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@4187c2a0
```

Did anyone encountered this problem and knows how to resolved it?

In SDK manager almost all are up to date.

Another thing that I've noticed is that if I have 2 instances of IntelijIdea opened, I can see the logs only in the first one opened...

Comment: where do you think it's unclear? Maybe play around with the log level if you don't want so verbose output...

Comment: I cannot see correctly the logs, the errors are not printed in red and so on...

Comment: Your own logging should be bound to your classes and you will have to create filters to see only those messages (typically done with "TAG"); Check out http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html The log you posted looks OK to me.

Comment: Another thing that I've noticed is that if I have 2 instances of IntelijIdea opened, I can see the logs only in the first one opened...